# How to initialise static arrays in D without a GC allocation?

Tags: arrays, performance, memory-management, d, static-array

In D, all array literals are dynamic arrays, and are therefore allocated by the GC.

Even in this simple example:

```
int[3] a = [10, 20, 30];
```

The array is heap-allocated and then copied into `a`.

How are you supposed to initialise a static array without heap-allocation?

You could do it manually:

```
int[3] a = void;
a[0] = 10;
a[1] = 20;
a[2] = 30;
```

But this is tedious at best.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I had no idea about this, I assumed local static arrays were allocated on the stack. :S

Comment: @Andrej: Yeah, surprised the hell out of me when I first found out. Apparently Don tried to convince Walter to make array literals static, but Walter is against it (can't find the thread atm). I imagine this could be a "gotcha" that haunts D for a while.

Comment: Also, this is exactly the type of thing which makes GC-less D totally impractical. It's just too damn easy to allocate memory without knowing about it.

Comment: Making array literal static by definition may be a problem but there is no reason the compiler couldn't optimize away the gc-allocate in that case, even make it a required optimization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
static const int[3] a = [10, 20, 30];
```

This will place a constant copy in the data segment. You can create a copy on the stack (that doesn't involve a heap allocation) with a simple assignment (`auto copy = a;`).

Comment: Ok, makes sense, although a bit tedious that you have to declare a static const version then copy it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* if you could declare the literal as `immutable` globally, then use that as the initializer, there's no heap allocation -- but I may be wrong, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be a bit mistaken: in http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/arrays.html#static-init-static

> ### Static Initialization of Static Arrays
>
> Static initalizations are supplied by a list of array element values
>   enclosed in [ ]. The values can be optionally preceded by an index and
>   a :. If an index is not supplied, it is set to the previous index plus
>   1, or 0 if it is the first value.
>
> -snip-
>
> These arrays are static when they appear in global scope. Otherwise, they need to be marked with const or static storage classes to make them static arrays.

with code example

```
int[3] a = [ 1:2, 3 ]; // a[0] = 0, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 3
```

that means that `const a[3] = [10, 20, 30];` won't/shouldn't allocate anything on the heap

Comment: To clarify, I'm talking about local arrays, not global ones. Sorry, I should have stated that. Also, I don't want the array to be const or static.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a compiler bug. I saw it in DMD's bugzilla. It should be fixed by now (DMD 2.055).

Answer (score 1):

2017 UPDATE: In any recent version of DMD, using an array initializer on a static array no longer allocates, even if the static array is a local variable (ie stack-allocated).

You can verify this yourself by creating a function where a static array is initialized, and then marking the function as @nogc and observing whether or not it compiles. Example:

```
import std.random;
import std.stdio;
int[4] testfunc(int num) @nogc
{
    return [0, 1, num, 3];
}

int main()
{
    int[4] arr = testfunc(uniform(0, 15));
    writeln(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Since testfunc() compiles despite being @nogc, we know that the array initializer does not allocate.